# Triple integral calculation gone wrong?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Calculate the volume of the solid bounded $K$ by 
>   $$z \geqslant x^2 + y^2 - 1, \quad z \leqslant \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + 1, \quad z \geqslant 0$$

The triple integral I set up is

$$ \iiint_K \text{d}x\text{d}y\text{d}z = \iint\left(\int_{x^2 + y^2 - 1}^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1} \text{d}z\right)\text{d}x\text{d}y  = \iint \left( \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + 2 - (x^2+y^2) \right) \text{d}x\text{d}y = \\ = \iint r(r + 2 - r^2) \, \text{d}r\text{d}\theta = 2\pi \int_{1}^2 (r^2 + 2r - r^3) \, \text{d}r = \frac {19\pi}6 .$$

But according to the key in the book the answer is supposed to be $29\pi/6$. I suspect the answer in the key is in fact incorrect but I am not entirely sure. What do you say? What result do you get?

Comment: What is the region in the $xy-plane$?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: The region in the xy-plane is the disk whose radius goes from $1$ (that's when we are at $z = 0$) and up to radius $2$ (the paraboloid-cone intersection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of $\frac{29\pi}{6}$ is correct, as you can see by computing the volume via the method of cylindrical shells:  $$\begin{align*} V &= \int_{r=0}^2 2\pi r \left(r+1 - \max(0,r^2-1)\right) \, dr \\ &= 2\pi \biggl( \int_{r=0}^1 r^2+r \, dr + \int_{r=1}^2 2r+r^2-r^3 \, dr \biggr) \\ &= \frac{29\pi}{6}. \end{align*}$$  Your computation does not properly take into account the fact that when $x^2 + y^2 < 1$, $z < 0$ for the lower bound of the interval of integration.  The correct integral is $$\iiint \, dz \, dy \, dx = \iint \int_{z=\max(0,x^2+y^2-1)}^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1} \, dz \, dy \, dx.$$  A cutaway image of the surfaces defining the boundary is shown below.  We want the volume enclosed below the cone, inside the paraboloid, **and above the disk/plane**.  [image]

Comment: But the radius of the circular region is 1 at the disk/plane, no? And then we go all the way up to the cone-paraboloid intersection, where the radius of the circular region is 2? Hence $1 \leqslant r \leqslant 2$.>
I do not understand why I would need to consider the region where r < 1? That is below the plane and therefore not contributing to the volume, no?
By the way I love the 3D-graph, how was it produced?

Comment: If you do not include the region for which $0 \le r \le 1$, then you are missing the entire volume of the cylindrical region below the cone and above the disk, which you can visualize in the figure.  Just because the paraboloid is below the $xy$-plane for $r < 1$ does not mean we do not integrate over this region.  It means that instead of taking the paraboloid as the lower limit of integration, we take the plane $z = 0$ as the lower limit.

Comment: Ah! I think I understand now what went wrong. By not considering $0 \leqslant r \leqslant 1$, we totally miss out the region which contains the cusp of the cone and therefore end up with a smaller volume. So I basically have to divide into two cases: (1) The volume from the cone-cusp up to the cone-paraboloid intersection and (2) the volume from $z = 0$ all the way up to the cusp. And I guess that's what you implicitly did with your "max"-notation, no?

Comment: That is exactly correct.

Comment: Thanks a heap heropop, much appreciated. Just out of curiosity, how did you produce that 3D figure? Mathematica, if I am not mistaken?

Comment: Oh, and to answer your other question:  the image was produced with *Mathematica* 9.  The that generated it is `ParametricPlot3D[{{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], r^2 - 1}, {r Cos[t], r Sin[t], r + 1}, {r Cos[t], r Sin[t], 0}}, {r, 0, 2.25}, {t, 0, 3 Pi/2},  PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 5]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you advance. You need to split the integral as

> $$ \iiint_K \text{d}x\text{d}y\text{d}z = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_0^{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - 1} \text{d}z\right)\text{d}x\text{d}y + \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{1}^{2}\left(\int_{x^2+y^2-1}^{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + 1} \text{d}z\right)\text{d}x\text{d}y.  $$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{z \geq x^{2} + y^{2} - 1\,,\quad z \leq \root{x^{2} + y^{2}} + 1\,,\quad
     z \geq 0}$

> \begin{align}&\left.\iiint\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\,\right\vert
> _{\,\max\braces{x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}\ -\ 1,0}\ \leq\ z\ \leq\
>   \root{x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}}\ +\ 1}
> \\[3mm]&=\left.\iiint\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\,\right\vert
> _{\,0\ \leq\ z\ \leq\ \root{\vphantom{\huge A}x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}}\ +\ 1
>   \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}\ \leq\ 1}}
> +
> \left.\iiint\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\,\right\vert
> _{\,x^{2}\ +\ y^{2} - 1\ \leq\ z\ \leq\ \root{\vphantom{\huge A}x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}}\ +\ 1
>   \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}\ >\ 1}}
> \\[3mm]&=\left.2\pi\iint\dd\rho\,\rho\int\dd z\,\right\vert
> _{\,0\ \leq\ z\ \leq\ \rho\ +\ 1
>   \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}\rho^{2}\ \leq\ 1}}
> +
> 2\pi\left.\iint\dd\rho\,\rho\,\dd z\,\right\vert
> _{\,\rho^{2}\ -\ 1\ \leq\ z\ \leq\ \rho\ +\ 1
>   \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}\rho^{2}\ >\ 1}}
> \end{align}

In the second integral we have an additional constraint:
$$
\rho^{2} - 1 \leq \rho + 1\quad\imp\quad\rho^{2} - \rho - 2 \leq 0
\quad\imp\quad -1\ \leq\ \rho\ \leq\ 2
$$

> Then
>   \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\left.\iiint\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\,\right\vert
> _{\,\max\braces{x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}\ -\ 1,0}\ \leq\ z\ \leq\
>   \root{x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}}\ +\ 1}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\pi\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\rho + 1}\rho\,\dd z\,\dd\rho
> +2\pi\int_{1}^{2}\int_{\rho^{2} - 1}^{\rho + 1}\rho\,\dd z\,\dd\rho
> \\[3mm]&=2\pi\
> \overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\pars{\rho^{2} + \rho}\,\dd\rho}^{\ds{=\ {5 \over 6}}}\
> -\
> 2\pi\
> \overbrace{\int_{1}^{2}\pars{\rho^{3} - \rho^{2} - 2\rho}\,\dd\rho}
> ^{\ds{=\ -\,{19 \over 12}}}\ =\
> \color{#66f}{\large{29 \over 6}\,\pi}
> \end{align}

Comment: I do not understand why we are considering $x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \leqslant 1$. That's the region below the plane, where $z < 0$, right? But we are only considering $z \geqslant 0$ along the paraboloid up to the cone and in the region the 2D circular regions radius goes from $1$ to $2$, no? What am I not seeing here?

Comment: @thelionkingrafiki Your conditions don't $\tt exclude$ the condition $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ and, in that case $z > 0$. Otherwise, $z > x^2 + y^2 - 1$. If you want to avoid that region you must add another condition: $x^2 + y^2 > 1$.